# getActivity() throws Null pointer exception after restarting app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an Activity and inside that activity , in onCreate I am doing fragment transaction. The first time I open the app ,everything works fine. But if I minimize my app (Not close. just pressing home button) , browse through other apps and come back to my app , then it crashes in getActivity() call of one of the fragment. This is the fragment related code:

MenuLayout.java

```
 public void startAnimation()
{
    final Random random = new Random();
    TimerTask animateTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    animateHandler(random.nextInt(SIZE*SIZE));
                }
            });
        }
    };
     timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(animateTask,1000,1500);
}
```

The above method is called in onCreateView.
It crashes in the getActivity() call inside the timer task. And yes, I do call timer.cancel in onPause().

Logcat:

```
06-28 22:33:06.136  31786-31809/sample.apps.sampleapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
Process: sample.apps.sampleapp, PID: 31786
java.lang.NullPointerException
        atsample.apps.sampleapp.MenuLayout$2.run(MenuLayout.java:155)
        at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Pooja I have updated the question with the logcat. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `getActivity()`. No need to add it as it is in `onCreate()`.
Just call `runUIOnThread()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work for you.

```
if(isAdded())//add this
                    animateHandler(random.nextInt(SIZE*SIZE));
```